# Finding subtraction of shifted tensor

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensor

I'm trying to figure out how to do shifting on a tensor that has `b (batch size), d (depth), h (hight) and w (width)` represented as following:

```
b, d, h, w = tensor.size()
```

So, I need to find the subtract between the shifted tensor and the tensor itself.

I'm thinking of using `torch.narrow` or `torch.concat` to do it for each side (shift the right, left, up then down side) and at each time I subtract from the same tensor side (tensor itself side), then at the end I will add/sum the differences/subtractions of each side (so I will have the final subtraction between the shifted and the tensor itself.

I'm new to PyTorch, it's easy to understand but struggling to implemented and maybe there is a simpler way (directly do the subtraction rather than working on each side and so on .....)

Any help on that please?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide an example.

Comment: This is the example which I explained above, taking the difference of the tensor with a shifted version of itself (either directly or working on each side then do the summation) @zihaozhihao

Comment: When you say shift, I also think of `torch.narrow`. It has `dim` argument that specify which dimension to narrow. So do you want to shift a tensor along a specific dimension, or something else? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure, but let's think of it as an image; so taking/shift the left side of a tensor to the right side and vice versa, the same for up and down @zihaozhihao

Comment: Does it sound like circular shift? shift the left side to the right side is like [2,3,4,5] -> [4,5,2,3]?

Comment: Yes exactly @zihaozhihao

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can split the tensor first, and then cat them in reverse order. I write a function to implement your thoughts. The `shift` should be a non-negative number and less than or equal to the size of `dim`.

```py
def tensor_shift(t, dim, shift):
    """
    t (tensor): tensor to be shifted. 
    dim (int): the dimension apply shift.
    shift (int): shift distance.
    """
    assert 0 <= shift <= t.size(dim), "shift distance should be smaller than or equal to the dim length."

    overflow = t.index_select(dim, torch.arange(t.size(dim)-shift, t.size(dim)))
    remain = t.index_select(dim, torch.arange(t.size(dim)-shift))

    return torch.cat((overflow, remain),dim=dim)
```

Here are some test results.

```py
a = torch.arange(1,13).view(-1,3)
a
#tensor([[ 1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6],
#        [ 7,  8,  9],
#        [10, 11, 12]])

shift(a, 0, 1) # shift 1 unit along dim=0
#tensor([[10, 11, 12],
#        [ 1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6],
#        [ 7,  8,  9]])

b = torch.arange(1,13).view(-1,2,3)
b
#tensor([[[ 1,  2,  3],
#         [ 4,  5,  6]],
#
#        [[ 7,  8,  9],
#         [10, 11, 12]]])

shift(b, 1, 1) # shift 1 unit along dim=1
#tensor([[[ 4,  5,  6],
#         [ 1,  2,  3]],
#
#        [[10, 11, 12],
#         [ 7,  8,  9]]])
```